# Get indexPath of "next" UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have some code when tapping on a cell of a table view. Under certain circumstances I want to call the function `tableView(_, didSelectRowAtIndexPath)` recursively for *the next* cell. That means that when I selected row 5, I want to select row 6, etc.

How can I get the indexPath of the *next* cell based on another row?

Comment: when you get the indexPath, perform all actions based on indexPath + 1.

Comment: Is there multiple sections in UITableView or single?

Comment: single section - @Siriss I can't add just 1 to an indexPath - it's not an Int value or something similar ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let nextIndexPath=NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row + 1, inSection: indexPath.section);

    // You should be sure than this NSIndexPath exist, and ...make what you want

}
```

Comment: While this answer may solve the problem, you should elaborate on it a bit and explain what your code does.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist, I 'm sorry but I understood this is the question: "How can I get the indexPath of the next cell based on another row?". And this is the answer: " let nextIndexPath=NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row + 1, inSection: indexPath.section);". This guy doesn't have any code than no work or something wrong in code. Anyway I don't know how provider more explanation. Sorry.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Didn't know you could initialize an NSIndexPath like this

Comment: @OnikIV As I said: this code may solve the OPs problem, but it would be a better answer if you could elaborate and explain *why* it solves the problem.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist you are wright. I usually try to explain, but in this case I though It was enough. Don't worry, the next, I'm going to add more explanation. Thanks.

Comment: This will not work if the next row is in the next section.

Comment: @OnikIV you said: "You should be sure than this NSIndexPath exist" how can I do this? (I have the same problem)

Answer (score 8):

Here's an answer in Swift:

```
private func nextIndexPath(for currentIndexPath: IndexPath, in tableView: UITableView) -> IndexPath? {
    var nextRow = 0
    var nextSection = 0
    var iteration = 0
    var startRow = currentIndexPath.row
    for section in currentIndexPath.section ..< tableView.numberOfSections {
        nextSection = section
        for row in startRow ..< tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) {
            nextRow = row
            iteration += 1
            if iteration == 2 {
                let nextIndexPath = IndexPath(row: nextRow, section: nextSection)
                return nextIndexPath
            }
        }
        startRow = 0
    }

    return nil
}
```

I use this code because I have a tableview with custom cells that contain a `UITextField`. It's configured with a Next button, and when that button is tapped, the focus is moved to the next `UITextField`.

To go to the previous indexPath, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56867271/

For an example project that includes a previous/next button as a toolbar above a keyboard, check out the example project:
https://github.com/bvankuik/TableViewWithTextFieldNextButton

Comment: Thks this works for next but What about Previous Index ?

Answer (score 4):

For previous indexPath I have made the following extension on UITableView 
( Swift 5.0 )

```
extension UITableView {

    func previousIndexPath(currentIndexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
        let startRow = currentIndexPath.row
        let startSection = currentIndexPath.section

        var previousRow = startRow
        var previousSection = startSection

        if startRow == 0 && startSection == 0 {
            return nil
        } else if startRow == 0 {
            previousSection -= 1
            previousRow = numberOfRows(inSection: previousSection) - 1
        } else {
            previousRow -= 1
        }

        return IndexPath(row: previousRow, section: previousSection)
    }

}
```

Comment: Good one, and it's a very natural way to make it an extension.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66864251/15026634) for the `nextIndexPath()` version of the method above.

Comment: A small oversight, I guess: A section can consists of zero rows. If you went back into a previous section with zero rows, you would return an indexPath with row = -1 (`numberOfRows(...) - 1`)?

Comment: @andreas1724 : for zero row section indexPath would not be used as there would be no call for Row For Index Path for such case. Also this is just helper for index Path. Hence the concept fo Zero row is not valid, as this is just about IndexPath. Finally as this has optional return type the issue wont be there for row==0 case as well, which is in code first returned check in IF condition.

Comment: @Bishal Ghimire: The initial `currentIndexPath` is not the problem. I agree with you, that `currentIndexPath` doesn't point to a zero-row-section. But consider this case: In section 0 is one row. In section 1 are zero rows (this is valid). In section 2 is one row. The `currentIndexPath` points to the first row in section 2. If you try to calculate the previous cells IndexPath, you would end up with IndexPath [1, -1]. It should be [0, 0] instead.

Answer (score 1):

this will work in swift 4 
for previous and next

```
let nextIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row + 1, section: indexPath.section)
let previousIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row - 1, section: indexPath.section)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an IndexPath extension method, I found its logic is a bit easier to understand than @Bart van Kuik's solution.

Written in Swift 5, Xcode 11, works for multi-section UITableView.

```
import UIKit

extension IndexPath {

    // Helper Methods
    func incrementRow(plus: Int=1) -> IndexPath {
        return IndexPath(row: row + plus, section: section)
    }

    func incrementSection(plus: Int=1) -> IndexPath {
        return IndexPath(row: 0, section: section + plus)
    }

    func next(in table: UITableView) -> IndexPath? {
        // if can find cell for next row, return next row's IndexPath
        if let _ = table.cellForRow(at: incrementRow()) {
            return incrementRow()
        }
        // cannot find next row, try to find row 0 in next section
        else if let _ = table.cellForRow(at: incrementSection()) {
            return incrementSection()
        }

        // can find neither next row nor next section, the current indexPath is already the very last IndexPath in the given table
        return nil
    }    
}
```

As for the previous IndexPath, @Bishal Ghimire's answer is valid, but here's the IndexPath version extension.

```
func previous(in table: UITableView) -> IndexPath? {
        // if the current indexPath is the very first IndexPath, then there's no previous
        if row == 0 && section == 0 { return nil }

        // if the current indexPath is the first row in a section, return table's previous section's last row's IndexPath
        if row == 0 {
            let lastRowInPrevSection = table.numberOfRows(inSection: section - 1) - 1
            return IndexPath(row: lastRowInPrevSection, section: section - 1)
        }
        // else just return previous row's IndexPath in the same section
        else {
            return IndexPath(row: row - 1, section: section)
        }
    }
```

You can drag & drop these method into any of your project and use them directly, in my case, I'm trying to highlight next cell's textField when the user hit return key, so the usage is like this:

```
...
if let nextIndexPath = currentIndexPath.next(in: myTableView),
   let nextCell = myTableView.cellForRow(at: nextIndexPath) as? MyCell {
   nextCell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
} else {
   // there's no next IndexPath in the given table, simply resign first responder for the current cell's textField
   currentCell.textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it seems to me that only(?) Bart van Kuiks answer currently considers the possibility, that a section could consists of none rows.
[image]

The other posters might correct their answers. Meanwhile I post my code for next and previous cells as `UITableView`-Extensions. Feel free to edit the code, if you find any mistakes.

```swift
extension UITableView {

    func indexPathOfCell(after indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
        var row = indexPath.row + 1
        for section in indexPath.section..<numberOfSections {
            if row < numberOfRows(inSection: section) {
                return IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
            }
            row = 0
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    func indexPathOfCell(before indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
        var row = indexPath.row - 1
        for section in (0...indexPath.section).reversed() {
            if row >= 0 {
                return IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
            }
            if section > 0 {
                row = numberOfRows(inSection: section - 1) - 1
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who liked @Bishal Ghimire's `previousIndexPath()` method, here is what the `nextIndexPath()` method would be.

```
import UIKit

extension UITableView {

    func nextIndexPath(currentIndexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
        let startRow = currentIndexPath.row
        let startSection = currentIndexPath.section

        var nextRow = startRow
        var nextSection = startSection

        if startSection == numberOfSections-1 && startRow == numberOfRows(inSection: startSection)-1 {
            return nil
        } else if startRow == numberOfRows(inSection: startSection)-1 {
            nextSection += 1
            nextRow = 0
        } else {
            nextRow += 1
        }

        return IndexPath(row: nextRow, section: nextSection)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can get the IndexOFObeject

```
NSUInteger indexOfTheObject = [Array indexOfObject:indexPath];
```

and for Cell tap:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *temp = [Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1]; 
temp...


}
```

Comment: They are not coding for Obj C.